# Convert numpy.ndarray object to matplotlib.Axes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a **numpy array** (current_ax) of shape (n,n) that consists of a **matplotlib.AxesSubplot** at each index. What I want to do is **convert current_ax to a matplotlib.Axes object**. Is there any possible way to do that?

I've attached the code below:

```python
current_ax = np.empty((3,3), dtype = object)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

data = []

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        current_ax[i,j] = fig.add_subplot(current_gs[i,j],label=f"{i}{j}")

        if i == 2:
           current_ax[i,j].set_ylabel(str(j))
        if j == 0:
            current_ax[i,j].set_xlabel(str(i))

        query = "y==" + str(j) + " and y_pred==" + str(i)
        col = 'y_proba' + str(i)
        results = df.query(query)
        data.append(results[col].item())

# Now I want to convert current_ax to an Axes object
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I think you can well imagine that you cannot convert a numpy array to a `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. So what is it that you *really* want to do? What is the end result?

Comment: I need the function I'm writing to return an Axes object. Also, I need to be able to set the title, xlabel, ylabel of the plot

Comment: You can return the complete array. Else you need to rethink why that function would need to return one axes while creating several. This might be a design flaw in your project.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way I can combine many Subplot objects into one axes object?

Comment: No. There isn't. This is really like asking if you can combine several cars into one big bus.